# Can you charge an iPhone 5 from a standard, non-Apple Micro USB cable?

Tags: iphone, lightning

Someone who has the new iPhone 5 said you can charge it from a regular Micro USB port but he's not tested it.

Can you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - just get a simple pass through adapter to plug the male USB into an adapter that fits in the lightning slot.

- http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD820ZM/A/lightning-to-micro-usb-adapter

There are also knock off and legitimate third party adapters being sold, so you can pick your price point / fit and finish / support sweet spot.

[image: Apple micro USB to Lightning adapter]

Answer (score 3):

Just to confirm what bmike said: I have one of Apple's micro-USB-to-Lightning adapters, and am using it with the cable from an Amazon Kindle. The combination works flawlessly on both the charging and data-synchronization fronts.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with Amazon Kindle cable. iPhone charger, Kindle Cable, Apple adapter, iPhone 5s. No luck though.
iPhone says: not a certified cable, might not work flawlessly. 
it does not charge. :(

Answer (score -1):

Too scared to try as Verizon Wireless said it will fry your Iphone 5

Comment: Hmm - perhaps some other qualifier was present in the conversation? [USB is 5.0 V DC at 500-900mA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) unless the device request a larger charging current. Since the iPhone 5 also charges from the same USB ports (albeit with different cable) it seems odd to presume this would fry anything.